# How to insert first item in combo box with text "SELECT" with default value 0 in C# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I am using C# windows application. My code is as below

```
var categoryList = _objCategoryManager.GetAll();
cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "Name";
cmbCategory.ValueMember = "Id";
cmbCategory.DataSource = categoryList;
```

Here categoryList  is of type IEnumerable. I want to insert item in ComboBox at 0 index i.e."--SELECT--"

Comment: ``categoryList.Insert(....``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot insert item to your `ComboBox` after data binding. Instead insert the item in a copy of your data source before, then do the binding.

If `categoryList` is `IEnumerable<T>` and not a `List<T>` then you should copy it to a `List<T>` so that you can add your default value at the first index:

```
var categoryList = _objCategoryManager.GetAll().ToList();
categoryList.Insert(0, new Category {Id = -1, Name = "--SELECT--"});
```

Comment: "Here categoryList is of type IEnumerable", and that type has no method named `Insert`

Comment: try `categoryList.Add` or `categoryList.ToList().Add(...)`, or `categoryList.Find(o => o.objId == objId).Name = "--SELECT"`

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman, thanks for pointing that out, I missed that part and thought it is a List to begin with because of name `categoryList`

Answer (score 4):

Simply insert it into your list, so something like

```
var categoryList = _objCategoryManager.GetAll().ToList();
cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "Name";
cmbCategory.ValueMember = "Id";

categoryList.Insert(0, new Category() { Name = "--SELECT--"} );

cmbCategory.DataSource = categoryList;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
categoryList.ToList().Find(o => o.ID == Convert.ToInt32(0)).Name = "--SELECT--";
```

Using LINQ, you can find the object you want to change (after binding) and modify that item.

Otherwise if you are adding an object into the list:

```
categoryList.ToList().Add(obj); // This should show the new item in the combo box
```

Ultimately your .GetAll() method should have returned the first one to be "--SELECT--" instead of trying to modify it afterwards.